# Controlling buzzer with assembly

Tags: arduino-uno, assembly, buzzer

I want to make a piezo buffer beeping with assembly code, but i haven't managed to yet. I have an Arduino UNO board (ATMega328p) and using avra and avrdude to build and load. The buzzer just stay silent. Here's my code:

```
.nolist
.include "m328pdef.inc"
.list

.equ _a = 141 ;(16000000 / 256) / 440(frequency of A) - 1

.cseg
  ;wgm02..0 = 7 (fast pwm, top = ocr0a)
  ;cs02..0 = 4 (N=256)
  ;com0b1..0 = 2 (clear on compare match, set at bottom)
  ldi r16, 0b00100011
  sts tccr0a, r16 ;need out!
  ldi r16, 0b00001100
  sts tccr0b, r16 ;need out!
  ;ocr0a = _a to obtain 440Hz
  ldi r16, 141
  out ocr0a, r16
  ;ocr0b = ocr0a/2 to obtain a duty cycle of 50%
  ldi r16, 71
  out ocr0b, r16
  ;enable output at D5 aka oc0b aka Arduino pin 5
  sbi ddrd, 5
  loop:
  rjmp loop
```

Wiring is good and the buzzer too, since it works with a C sketch

EDIT: I found my answer by myself (with the help of answerers). I was accessing IO ports (tccr0a and tccr0b) with sts, while i had to use out. (tccr0a and tccr0b are IO ports defined in "m328pdef.inc" as IO addresses, not as memory addresses)

Comment: A common way to gain more insight in these sort of cases is to:

  * compile with optimizations turned off:  -O0
  * tell gcc to preserve intermediate artifacts (the assembly file generated: -S or --save-temps)

Comment: I don't use gcc. I use avra

Comment: You said that the buzzer works with a C sketch. How did you compile it?

Comment: For compiling C sketches i use Arduino IDE, that uses gcc i think, but for asm compiling i use avra, the AVRStudio assembler

Comment: Right. My advice was to observe the intermediate file produced by gcc (you can tell it to preserve the assembly sources) and use them as reference for debugging your own asm program.

Comment: What does `tccr0a` mean? Is it an I/O address? Or a data address maybe? And what about `ocr0a`?

Comment: `I want to make a piezo buffer beeping with assembly code` - why?

Comment: Yes, tccr0a is an IO address, my error was to use sts
And I use assembly because code is faster and I save much memory, and I'm masochist

Comment: In this instance, assembly is not significantly faster. From the C program `main(){TCCR0A=0x23; TCCR0B=0x0c; OCR0A=141; OCR0B=71; DDRD|=1<<5; for(;;);}`, gcc generates almost exactly the assembly you wrote, except it uses `out` instead of `sts`. By writing directly in assembly, you only save the initialization done by the C runtime (13 cycles, done only once). That being said, being a masochist is a perfectly valid reason for writing assembly. Or at least I like to believe so. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I translated you program to GNU as syntax, and it works as expected: I
get a 440 Hz square wave on digital pin 5. Here is the
translated program:

```
#include <avr/io.h>

; I'm too lazy to always type the full name of these macros
#define io(reg) _SFR_IO_ADDR(reg)
#define mem(reg) _SFR_MEM_ADDR(reg)

_a = 141 ;(16000000 / 256) / 440(frequency of A) - 1

  ;wgm02..0 = 7 (fast pwm, top = ocr0a)
  ;cs02..0 = 4 (N=256)
  ;com0b1..0 = 2 (clear on compare match, set at bottom)
  ldi r16, 0b00100011
  sts mem(TCCR0A), r16
  ldi r16, 0b00001100
  sts mem(TCCR0B), r16
  ;ocr0a = _a to obtain 440Hz
  ldi r16, 141
  out io(OCR0A), r16
  ;ocr0b = ocr0a/2 to obtain a duty cycle of 50%
  ldi r16, 71
  out io(OCR0B), r16
  ;enable output at D5 aka oc0b aka Arduino pin 5
  sbi io(DDRD), 5
  loop:
  rjmp loop
```

As shown in my comment to your question, I suspect the problem is a
misunderstanding of the meaning of things like `tccr0a` and `ocr0a`.
In the translated version above, I admit I do *not* know what `TCCR0A`
and co. mean. And I need not to: I can treat these as opaque
identifiers, as the avr-libc recommends to *always* use them with the
macros `_SFR_IO_ADDR()` and `_SFR_MEM_ADDR()`, which provide the I/O
address and the data address of the register respectively.

I do not know how to use avra, so I cannot tell you how the get the I/O
or data address of a register. But there certainly must be a way. You
should always use the data address with `sts` and the I/O address with
`out` and `sti`.